GeoServer SLD Holding patterns arrow direction
I'm trying to add an arrow to a holding pattern. For most of the time this solution Drawing arrow on line using SLD of GeoServer? is working well, but there is geometries that are making the arrow to turn perpendicular and not follows the line.

Any idea why this happens and how could be fixed?
WKT Not Working:
POLYGON ((55.471134167 25.111157722, 55.50182137362533 25.094054238419098, 55.5325 25.076944444, 55.536525023350954 25.07507597817018, 55.540801570110496 25.073742638712066, 55.54524344844729 25.07297129636891, 55.54976114139581 25.072777495578542, 55.554263607327385 25.0731651418559, 55.55866011082922 25.074126423251993, 55.56286204747665 25.075641967455887, 55.56678472610169 25.0776812314062, 55.57034907298079 25.08020311563966, 55.57348322387237 25.08315679111473, 55.576123972006485 25.086482721996383, 55.576123972 25.086482722, 55.57822223857912 25.09012260409415, 55.57972874014795 25.093995395274018, 55.58061290484049 25.098022651007824, 55.580856759998504 25.102122790198475, 55.58045530109449 25.106212747110828, 55.579416598283835 25.110209654027358, 55.57776163801816 25.114032520559284, 55.575523902516 25.117603875557894, 55.572748695234154 25.12085133827708, 55.56949222569641 25.123709086826945, 55.56582047200333 25.126119194004858, 55.565820472 25.126119194, 55.534835747159335 25.14340041732765, 55.50384225 25.160675194, 55.49940748285586 25.162620137634075, 55.49469437310885 25.163922956649067, 55.48981565009213 25.164552487934635, 55.48488801273341 25.16449367290157, 55.48002933246291 25.163747918434055, 55.47535582778258 25.162333063165878, 55.470979278784895 25.16028294989583, 55.46700434891314 25.157646614475315, 55.46352607858159 25.15448711076139, 55.46062761099859 25.150880000000786, 55.460627611 25.15088, 55.4585250002311 25.147223612239628, 55.457019630511624 25.14333327543896, 55.45614218401516 25.139288432119223, 55.45591051400149 25.135171671894568, 55.45632928524448 25.13106704444144, 55.45738988407469 25.127058343323657, 55.45907059944307 25.123227395729625, 55.461337070886174 25.119652393001278, 55.46414299386521 25.116406295949098, 55.46743106776798 25.113555347375605, 55.47113416700471 25.111157722006972, 55.471134167 25.111157722))

WKT Working:
POLYGON ((55.143529417 25.457425806, 55.112739075030674 25.47448139635423, 55.08194 25.49153056, 55.08194000000628 25.49153056000933, 55.0782153961302 25.493917869529692, 55.074905918482614 25.49676018494095, 55.07207922714239 25.499999424142533, 55.0697931303718 25.5035693889966, 55.068094401447674 25.507397116394475, 55.067017819670625 25.511404367891704, 55.06658545537692 25.515509227628133, 55.06680621388816 25.519627776001027, 55.06767564811349 25.523675804964352, 55.0691760440686 25.527570539922895, 55.071276778 25.531232333, 55.07127677800291 25.53123233299839, 55.07391618893461 25.53456587472185, 55.0770526456369 25.537528208018102, 55.08062284520991 25.540059511931723, 55.08455471164455 25.542108666161962, 55.08876885183553 25.543634285179532, 55.09318016067111 25.544605555608193, 55.097699542591286 25.54500285980345, 55.102235714560784 25.544818172909334, 55.106697053688485 25.54405522529081, 55.11099345178462 25.54272942702604, 55.115038139 25.540867556, 55.145900433496855 25.5237919535568, 55.176753944 25.506709889, 55.17675394399585 25.50670988899391, 55.18045950387793 25.50431207029567, 55.183749165658476 25.50146268048427, 55.18655597836599 25.498219737682913, 55.18882283630027 25.494649268385672, 55.19050363988772 25.49082396139526, 55.19156423113605 25.486821686437693, 55.19198308487299 25.482723907770726, 55.19175174202003 25.478614025204696, 55.19087497647237 25.474575676385772, 55.18937069261611 25.47069103492685, 55.18726955599987 25.46703913900007, 55.18462759620133 25.46370867315247, 55.18148989517076 25.460749609000256, 55.17791973382433 25.458221592675446, 55.17398909614626 25.456175578181988, 55.16977721873912 25.454652802095673, 55.165368995480655 25.4536839539852, 55.16085326925016 25.453288559121283, 55.156321044872 25.453474585792833, 55.15186365894467 25.454238285062853, 55.14757094305439 25.455564266159673, 55.143529417 25.457425806))

SLD:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Holding Pattern</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Holding Pattern</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Holding Pattern</Name>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#ADD8E6</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.8</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="startPoint">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </Geometry>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>30</Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                  <ogc:PropertyName>geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:Function>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>


Can you add the WKT for a working and not working loop and the sld

Yes, the SLD is basically copy and paste from the link, but here they are.

both of those polygons work for me - are you running a recent version of GeoServer?

I was with 2.25.1, but updated to the latest - 2.26 and the result is the same.

I think I found it. Prove me wrong, pls.
1.I transform the polygon to a linestring -> didn't worked;
2. removed the last point to the linestring -> worked;
In order to do a POLYGON we need to close the shape with same point on both ends. So based on the shape points direction (CW or Counter CW) the next point for calculating the angle will be same point and that will mess it up.

@IanTurton but that opens the question why had worked for you :D

How did you convert the polygon to a linestring? But it may have worked for me because I pasted the WKT in to QGIS and saved it from there.

ST_GeomFromText

ST_GeomFromText would give a polygon for the WKT you have included

yes, of course, I changed the type to LINESTRING.

Just use them as polygons should work

it didn't work. I can't keep them as polygons as well.

I don't understand - the WKT you supplied are polygons, using those polygons works with that SLD

Using those polygons is not working that SLD for me on the geoserver.
